# Whats the best way to do pagination in BigQuery tables when you want to keep retrieving results using pagination?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am working on an analytical project which runs query and processes the result and stores in the BigQuery on monthly basis in Table A. As BigQuery  cannot be used as  transactional query and we have to show this results to our users so we decided to save the result back to the on-prem SQl Server relationalDB (we decided it would be to expensive to go with CloudSQL for now so we decided on prem relationaldb). I have decided to use pagination to read from BQ and save the result back to on-prem relationalDB. However, I cannot seem to figure out, as this is a monthly process, every month the data is appended to TableA, how would I know where to begin from the next time I want to read the result? I do not want to re-read the same values I read before.

Should I save pageToken somewhere so that I know where to begin from? However, do I also need to save the jobID?

```
 private void getMonthlyStats(String dataSetName, String table) {

    // Identify the table itself
    TableId tableId = TableId.of(dataSetName, table);

    TableResult result = bigQuery.listTableData(tableId, BigQuery.TableDataListOption.pageSize(100));

    do {
        result.getValues().forEach(x-> {
           // save the result back to relationalDB.
        });
    }while(result.getNextPageToken()!=null);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your table data include a timestamp you can use for filtration?  If so, I'd consider using the [BigQuery storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/) directly, and simply setting a [row_restriction](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/rpc/google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1#google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.ReadSession.TableReadOptions) filter when creating the read session to only return rows that have a timestamp higher than your watermark time.

The pagination mechanism from tabledata.list is not suitable for this kind of resumption/incremental read pattern. You'd need individual tables for each time window to read in this fashion, or a time partitioned table where you can reference partitions individually for reading.

Comment: Yes, we support a month based filtration. We have partitioned the table based on the month we run the process. I was thinking about the query-based partition approach, however, it expects me to create a temp table that I wanted to avoid (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/paging-results#paging_through_query_results). But I guess reading from comments above, it seems I am left with the query based partition approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, read this [page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/paging-results#bigquery_browse_table-nodejs) about BigQuery pagination in Nodejs. I suggest you create a monthly scheduled script/job that does the following:

1. Submit a job to Bigquery.
2. Set `configuration.query.destinationTable`.
3. Poll the job for completion.
4. Page over the results from the destination table.
5. INSERT OR UPDATE the rows in relationalDB.
6. Run completes when pageToken is null.
7. Save the last known pageToken and Etag somewher (e.g. in relationalDB).
8. Next time you run the job retrieve the last pageToken.
9. Start the same query with that pageToken.
10. You could use the Etag to check whether this last page has changed. However, doing an INSERT OR UPDATE in your relationalDB already mitigates for duplicates.

I would suggest you create a small test table with 50 rows. Then run the job as described above. Then append 50 rows and run the job again and see what happens.

I would also suggest you read more about the scenario where data in your previous pages might have changed. In this scenario, you could make use of the `Etag` property.

Comment: Thanks. :) My confusion was more around the pageToken, as getNextPageToken will be null, saving null value in the db how would it help me out? You mentioned retrieve the last pageToken, however wouldn’t it be null in this case? Thanks for the eras suggestion, however we are not updating any data but adding new rows

Comment: That would then be the last pageToken that is not null. Which is the token of the last page that could be incomplete. Then you could also add the Etag property, which acts as a checksum of the page. Then in the next run fetch that page, check if it has changed with that Etag (probably it has). And UPDATE OR INSERT your sql db, so any duplicates won't be inserted again. Then continue to the next pages until it completes again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to be using pagination, since there is no guarantee that rows will always be returned in the same order.  Ideally, your monthly data should be inserted with some kind of date attached.  That would make it easy to select only the data inserted since the last download.  If it is not, I'd strongly suggest you revisit your data model.

You may also want to consider partitioning your BigQuery table by date to reduce the cost and improve the performance of queries to extract the data.

Comment: It does have a date associated with it. I thought about that approach, basically, I have to use query-based pagination. However, it expects me to have a temp table according to the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/paging-results#paging_through_query_results). I was trying to avoid doing that. But if the api based pagination does not work then I might take that approach.

Comment: We have partitioned the table based on the month, so we would be reading fewer data per month.We have partitioned the table based on the month we run the process.